# Can a child do a citizen's arrest?

Tags: england-and-wales, germany, citizens-arrest

I'm really interested to know if it's legal in London (UK) and Germany for a child, say at 13 or even aged 8, to do a citizen's arrest? On an adult, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**Short answer**: Yes, but with some limitations - none of which are age-related so do not restrict a citizen's arrest to adults only.

**Long answer:** The relevant legislation is at [s.24A of the Policeand Criminal Evidence Act 1984](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/60/section/24A?timeline=false) which begins with:

> (1) **A person** other than a constable may arrest without a warrant—

Which is followed by the limitations on its use:

> - (a) anyone who is in the act of committing an indictable offence;
> - (b) anyone whom he has reasonable grounds for suspecting to be committing an indictable offence.
>
> (2) Where an indictable offence has been committed, a person other than a constable may arrest without a warrant—
>
> - (a) anyone who is guilty of the offence;
> - (b) anyone whom he has reasonable grounds for suspecting to be guilty of it.
>
> (3) But the power of summary arrest conferred by subsection (1) or (2) is exercisable only if—
>
> - (a) the person making the arrest has reasonable grounds for believing that for any of the reasons mentioned in subsection (4) it is necessary to arrest the person in question; and
> - (b) it appears to the person making the arrest that it is not reasonably practicable for a constable to make it instead.
>
> (4) The reasons are to prevent the person in question—
>
> - (a) causing physical injury to himself or any other person;
> - (b) suffering physical injury;
> - (c) causing loss of or damage to property; or
> - (d) making off before a constable can assume responsibility for him.
>
> (5) This section does not apply in relation to an offence under [Part 3](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/part/III?timeline=false) or [3A](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/part/3A?timeline=false) of the Public Order Act 1986. [ being *racial hatred* and *hatred against persons on religious grounds or grounds of sexual orientation* respectively.]

The opening phrase of "*a person*" is not defined in this or any related Act, nor has the question of age in this context ever been considered the courts (as far as I have been able to establish) - so in the absence of any statutory definition or case law its [normal and everyday meaning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/person?locale=en) should be used.

Answer (score 9):

This will probably depend on what you understand as a citizen's arrest and will probably differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.

---

In Germany the closest thing to citizen's arrest is called **Vorläufige Festnahme** ([Provisional arrest](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stpo/englisch_stpo.html#p1155)) and probably contains a different set of conditions when it can be used.

> [§ 127 Provisional arrest](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stpo/englisch_stpo.html#p1155) 
> (1) If a person is caught in the act or is being pursued, **any person** shall be authorised to arrest him provisionally, even without judicial order, if there is **reason to suspect flight** or **if his identity cannot be immediately established**. The establishment of the identity of a person by the public prosecution office or by police officers shall be governed by section 163b (1).
> ...

Through the usage of the word **jedermann** (any person), a child (minor) can also exercise this right.

---

**Sources**:

- [§ 127 Provisional arrest - German Code of Criminal Procedure
  (Strafprozeßordnung – StPO)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stpo/englisch_stpo.html#p1155)

Comment: While a child has the *right* it most likely doesn't have the *means* and might lack the knowledge that they *could*/*should* do so. That however, is not a *legal* problem. // If a Corläufige FEstnahme lacks any foundation it quickly turns into Freiheitsberaubung.

Comment: @Trish Preventing someone to escape, the main usage, is within the capabilities of many minors. Whether they understand the legal aspects is another question. Being a minor they may not be held responsible if they don't get everything right.

Comment: True - a tiny point that might be well added (though 12-18 is possibly liable)

Comment: @Trish: Criminal Responsability starts at 14 in Germany.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

Under [s24A](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/60/section/24A/2012-07-25) of the *Police and Criminal Evidence Act* 1984 the power is given to “A person other than a constable”. A child is “a person other than a constable”.